# Finding an optimal solution to a system of linear equations in c++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, matrix, equation

Here's the problem:

I am currently trying to create a control system which is required to find a solution to a series of complex linear equations without a unique solution.

My problem arises because there will ever only be six equations, while there may be upwards of 20 unknowns (usually way more than six unknowns).  Of course, this will not yield an exact solution through the standard Gaussian elimination or by changing them in a matrix to reduced row echelon form.

However, I think that I may be able to optimize things further and get a more accurate solution because I know that each of the unknowns cannot have a value smaller than zero or greater than one, but it is free to take on any value in between them.

Of course, I am trying to create code that would find a correct solution, but in the case that there are multiple combinations that yield satisfactory results, I would want to minimize `Sum of (value of unknown * efficiency constant) over all unknowns`, i.e. Sigma[x<sub>I</sub>*e<sub>I</sub>] from I=0 to n, but finding an accurate solution is of a greater priority.

Performance is also important, due to the fact that this algorithm may need to be run several times per second.

So, does anyone have any ideas to help me on implementing this?

Comment: Linear programming? Even a naive solver should be fast enough for reasonable values of "several".

Comment: Maybe you should look at the [CLooG](http://www.cloog.org/) or [PPL](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl) libraries (used by GCC) for linear programming problems.

Comment: You can check [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/), or more generally the [LP solvers list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) at Wikipedia.

Comment: I forgot about linear programming.  It's been a long time since I've had to do it.  It's coming back to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You might just want to stick to linear programming with equality and inequality constraints, but here's an interesting exact solution that does not incorporate the constraint that your unknowns are between 0 and 1.

Here's a powerpoint discussing your problem: http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/08-min-norm.pdf

I'll translate your problem into math to make things a bit easier to figure out:

you have a 6x20 matrix A and a vector x with 20 elements. You want to minimize (x^T)e subject to Ax=y. According to the slides, if you were just minimizing the sum of x, then the answer is A^T(AA^T)^(-1)y. I'll take another look at this as soon as I get the chance and see what the solution is to minimizing (x^T)e (ie your specific problem).

Edit: I looked in the powerpoint some more and near the end there's a slide entitled "General norm minimization with equality constraints". I am going to switch the notation to match the slide's:

Your problem is that you want to minimize ||Ax-b||, where b = 0 and A is your e vector and x is the 20 unknowns. This is subject to Cx=d. Apparently the answer is:

x=(A^T A)^-1 (A^T b -C^T(C(A^T A)^-1 C^T)^-1 (C(A^T A)^-1 A^Tb - d))

it's not pretty, but it's not as bad as you might think. There's really aren't that many calculations. For example (A^TA)^-1 only needs to be calculated once and then you can reuse the answer. And your matrices aren't that big.

Note that I didn't incorporate the constraint that the elements of x are within [0,1].

Comment: Inequality constraints *should* be a problem, otherwise [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution for what I am doing is with Linear Programming.  It is starting to come back to me, but if I have other problems I will post them in their own dedicated questions instead of turning this into an encyclopedia.